# how to find nginx command without problems

Tags: nginx, bash

I have a problem with nginx, doing:

```
nginx -t
```

i get -bash: nginx: command not found

```
root@vpslive /# find /usr/ -name 'nginx'
/usr/share/nginx
```

the nginx server is running, i'm afraid I'll have problems when I restart

how can i solve?

```
ps -aux
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nk6u2.png)

seems /usr/sbin/nginx has been deleted!! i have some problems if i restart nginx right? thanks

```
pstree -p
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLIIj.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFJxS.png)

Comment: Are you sure nginx is running try `ps aux | grep nginx` to check if it running first. If it running try to locate directory it is install in. It is very hard to help you when you dont state what is your config and what system you are running on

Comment: i have updated the question. nginx seems runnin on /usr/sbin/nginx but this file doesn't exists

Comment: Try cd /usr/sbin/nginx  then try nginx status or ./nginx status nginx -t checks if your config file is right or wrong . The question is what do you want to do with nginx -t

Comment: /usr/sbin/nginx
-bash: /usr/sbin/nginx: No such file or directory

Comment: try /usr/sbin then nginx -t

Comment: root@vpsname /var/lib/nginx # cd /usr/sbin
root@vpsname /usr/sbin # nginx -t
-bash: nginx: command not found

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80271/discussion-between-augusto-murri-and-ahmed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### EDIT

nginx package in the system was uninstalled. Reinstalling the package resolves the issue.

---

Do a `ps -eF | grep nginx`, and note the PID; then do a `ls -a /proc/{PID}/exe`.

`/proc/{PID}/exe` should be a symbolic link to the executable file run with said PID.

Comment: ls -la /proc/16348/exe
lrwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data 0 Jul 14 12:11 /proc/16348/exe -> /usr/sbin/nginx (deleted)

Comment: try running `/usr/sbin/nginx -t` then

Comment: /usr/sbin/nginx -t
-bash: /usr/sbin/nginx: No such file or directory

Comment: that's funny, either you're running a container (docker/lxd/openvz) or you got something very weird with your system (rootkit?). Can you show us your `pstree -p` output?

Comment: updated with screenshot... no a simple webserver debian based nginx php7 mysql for running  one (important) website

Comment: let's continue [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80271/discussion-between-augusto-murri-and-ahmed)

Answer (score 0):

If your nginx service is running on port 80. you can get nginx binary path from available running process.

```
# lsof -i :80
```

It will give the process ID of nginx. then find nginx binary path from the output of

```
# lsof -i -p PID_from_last_commond | grep nginx
```

Alternatively, you can search nginx binary on a server with "locate" command

```
# locate nginx
```

Note: you need to install and update locate command if not present on server.

Comment: nginx      1097             root  txt    REG                8,1    1004952     811 /usr/sbin/nginx (deleted)

Comment: try to locate nginx binary is present on server or not." # locate nginx ". If it is present just kill all the running nginx service /process and start nginx again.

Comment: locate nginx doesn't find nothing

Comment: Try to update locate backend db "#updatedb" is the command. and then search "#locate nginx". If still there is no nginx binary. Then it means binary got deleted from server.  It is serious things. Take a backup of all the configuration and document root folder. Reinstall nginx package. ( remove available packges if conflicts" and start the service.

Comment: i don't know how... /usr/sbin/nginx has been deleted

Comment: @AugustoMurri, it may be some rootkit or some accidentally deleted binary. If you want to recover service. Restore that binary from backup Or remove current nginx completely and reinstall it. (Take require backup of config and data before un-install)